# Neo4j merge two query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I would like to merge these two queries together:

Query 1 (and result):

```
MATCH (Professor)-[:liest]->(Vorlesung)-[:wird_gehoert]->(Studenten)
RETURN Professor.Name, COUNT(Studenten.MatrNr) 

Professor.Name  COUNT(Studenten.MatrNr)
Augustinus  2
Russel  2
Sokrates    4
Kant    4
Popper  1
```

Query 2 (and result):

```
MATCH (Professor)-[:liest]->(Vorlesung)
RETURN Professor.Name, sum(Vorlesung.SWS)

Name    COUNT(Studenten.MatrNr)
Augustinus  2
Russel  2
Kant    4
Sokrates    4
Popper  1
```

I tried this:

```
MATCH (Professor)-[:liest]->(Vorlesung)-[:wird_gehoert]->(Studenten)
RETURN Name, COUNT(Studenten.MatrNr), sum(Vorlesungen.SWS)
```

But i receive the wrong answer:

```
Professor.Name  COUNT(Studenten.MatrNr) sum(Vorlesung.SWS)
Augustinus  2   4
Russel  2   5
Sokrates    4   14
Kant    4   16
Popper  1   2
```

What can I do to merge the two queries together?

Comment: Take a look at UNION operator.

Comment: The second query and its results don't seem to match. The results show `COUNT(Studenten.MatrNr)`, but the query wants to return `sum(Vorlesung.SWS)`. Can you correct this? Also, what does `Vorlesung.SWS` represent?

Answer (score 0):

If you return just the results of your match:

```
MATCH (Professor)-[:liest]->(Vorlesung)-[:wird_gehoert]->(Studenten)
RETURN Professor, Vorlesung, Studenten
```

You'll see that each row will be a combination of the professor, the lecture, and a student in that lecture. This means that students who are in multiple lectures for the same professor will appear multiple times for that professor (once per separate lecture) which may throw off your count for students, and you'll also have the same lecture showing up as many times as there are students for that lecture, which will throw off your sum() calculation.

To avoid calculating over duplicate entries, you'll want to process the query a bit differently. This is my best guess, but it would help to know what `Studenten.MatrNr` and `Vorlesung.SWS` represent. If `MatrNr` is meant to be unique number for a student, then it's better to count the distinct student nodes instead:

```
MATCH (Professor)-[:liest]->(Vorlesung)-[:wird_gehoert]->(Studenten)
// need to aggregate Vorlesung so we get an accurate count of distinct students
WITH Professor, collect(DISTINCT Vorlesung) as Vorlesungen, count(DISTINCT Studenten) as StudentenCount
// need to unwind back to rows so we can sum across distinct Vorlesung
UNWIND Vorlesungen as Vorlesung
RETURN Professor, sum(Vorlesung.SWS) as swsSum, StudentenCount
```